# find the constants of a PDF given the mean

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

given a RV variable with the following density funciton:

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 0, & \text{ }x<0, \\ \\ c1, & \text{ } 0\le x < 1, \\ \\c2, & \text{ } 1\le x < 2,\\ \\ 0, & \text{ }x>2,\end{cases}$$

and mean of $\mu= 1.5$

Find $c1$ and $c2$?

Aren't they just both equal to 1?

I'm just getting confused because he mean was given. Since the mean was given does that mean $c2=2$ and $c1=1$? or is the question just trying to throw me off.

Comment: Why do you think that they both equal to $1$?

Comment: the integral of the pdfs are equal to 1. So if I took the integral of c1 from 0 to 1 it would just equal to c1 = 1.

Comment: Why from $0$ to $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly cannot be the case that $c_1=c_2=1$. Because if that was the case, the function $f$ would not be a valid probability density function since

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx\ne 1$$

To find $c_1$ and $c_2$, you can use the followings facts:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = 1$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx = \mathbb{E}[X] = 1.5$$

Comment: Ok that makes sense thank you. BTW are they both 0.75? I'll do the calculations but just wondering

Comment: @user367640 By plugging in $0.75$, it doesn't seem to be the correct answer. But the calculation should be easy.